# How to stop graph plots from appearing when trying to display multiple images using subplot in Python?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm reading all the necessary images using

```
    for i in range(size):
      img = mpimg.imread(PATHTOMYIMAGE)
      img2 = mpimg.imread(PATHTOMYIMAGE2)
      f, axarr = plt.subplots(size,2)
      axarr[i,0].imshow(img)
      axarr[i,1].imshow(img2)
    plt.show()
```

The images are all displayed correctly, but there are also graph plots drawn underneath each image such as so:[image: Correctly displayed images with the unwanted graph plots]

I'm unsure where they come from as no other sources seem to explain what they are.

There was only one other use of `plt` earlier which was initialising using `plt.figure()`.

How can I disable these graph plots and keep just the image pairs? Thanks!

Comment: for future questions, i recomend you to add the imported libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solutio for your requirement

```
for i in range(1):
  img = mpimg.imread(PATHTOMYIMAGE)
  img2 = mpimg.imread(PATHTOMYIMAGE2)
  f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
  axarr[i].imshow(img)
  axarr[i+1].imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

in you case, for loop can be avoided

```
  img = mpimg.imread(PATHTOMYIMAGE)
  img2 = mpimg.imread(PATHTOMYIMAGE2)
  f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
  axarr[0].imshow(img)
  axarr[1].imshow(img2)
  plt.show()
```

the answer about where other frames comes, is the following

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(10,2)
```

first parameter are how many rows, second one, is number of columns, in this example, there´re 10 rows, 2 columns as follows
[image: grid]